Why does my solidify modifer change thickness?
I am using version 2.93.16. However, this is such a fundamental problem, the version probably doesn't make much difference.
I am posting that as a "answer my own question" because I found that answer while creating this, and other newbies may benefit from it.  Also I welcome any additional explanations.
I am trying to create a box with a circular hole. I've seen the recommendation to:

subdivide the face
remove a face
add a cylinder
modify the cylinder with a solid...

but I had an issue.
Here are the specific steps:
Create a 1m box.

Make it 10 by 4 by 4

Next in edit mode, remove the top.

Back to object mode, set the Scale To
(I'm not fully clear on this... I guess this makes the scale uniform for the new size, because I notice when I solidify it, the wall thickness varies according to how it was scaled, and this seems to "normalize" it. )

Add a modifier to solidify the box.

Next, into edit mode.  I subdivide the vertical lines by 2, connect them with an edge, then subdivide the the new horizontal lines by 2 and connect them with an edge. I now have a face I can remove, as shown here.
But look at the red arrow I added.

The "solidify" where the new face has been added is thicker.
There are no vertexes to grab, and no inner edges to move.
So, something that solves it is below.

How do I prevent it? Apparently by checking the "Even Thickness" box.

But, why did it do this in the first place? And how is it related to the "Apply Scale" if at all?
I, and maybe other newbies, want to know.
Thanks

Even Thickness and Apply Scale are 2 different things, if you scale in Object mode you need to apply the scale if you want the Solidify to be equal in all axis, as for the Even Thickness it garantees that the extrusion keeps the same thickness for all the walls despite the topology

Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, the answer section is reserved exclusively for answering the OP question. To ask for clarification, post comments or replies please use the comments section instead. If you have the same problem or a different question please use the Ask Question button at the top right. If you want to add additional information or further developments, use the edit button below the original post instead. This post may be removed or converted to a comment.
